# Convert uint16 array to string

Tags: go

I have an array of uint16 coming from WinAPI `PROCESSENTRY32.szExeFile` that I wanna convert to a string.

Here's my var type

```
var hello [260]uint16
```

now I need to convert hello to a string. How can I do that?

**Edit**

Here's what I've tried:

```
func szExeFileToString(ByteString [260]uint16) string {
    b := make([]byte, len(ByteString))

    for i, v := range ByteString {
        b[i] = byte(v)
    }

    return string(b)
}
```

However, this returns pretty weird strings...
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U66GU.png) (the function should convert Windows process names in the `PROCESSENTRY32.szExeFile` (-> `[260]uint16`)  type to string)

Comment: What format should the string take? What have you tried? Show your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @Flimzy question edited.

Comment: Don't use links to images of text--copy and paste the text directly into the question instead.

Comment: Don't put the solution in your question--instead create an answer.

Comment: @Flimzy yeah well that's still not a reason to downvote my question

Comment: Those are all valid reasons to downvote your question, whether you like it or not. They are all also things that you can easily fix, and have the downvotes reversed.

Answer (score 3):

> [package windows](https://www.godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows)
>
> `import "golang.org/x/sys/windows"`
>
> [func UTF16ToString](https://www.godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows#UTF16ToString)
>
> ```
> func UTF16ToString(s []uint16) string
> ```
>
> UTF16ToString returns the UTF-8 encoding of the UTF-16 sequence s,
>   with a terminating NUL removed.

---

Use `windows.UTF16ToString`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    var szExeFile [260]uint16
    szExeFile = [260]uint16{'e', 'x', 'e', 'F', 'i', 'l', 'e'}

    exeFile := windows.UTF16ToString(szExeFile[:])
    fmt.Println(exeFile)
}
```

Output:

```
exeFile
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it. Here's the fixed function to help anyone that gets into this question to convert `PROCESSENTRY32.szExeFile` result to a string.

Note: I've also forgot to use `kernel32.NewProc("Process32FirstW")` and `kernel32.NewProc("Process32NextW")` instead of `kernel32.NewProc("Process32First")`

```
func szExeFileToString(ByteString [260]uint16) string {
    var End = 0

    for i, _ := range ByteString {
        if ByteString[i] == 0 {
            End = i
            break
        }
    }

    return syscall.UTF16ToString(ByteString[:End])
}
```